# How to prevent 'write.csv' in R from converting DATE column from [YYYY-MM-DD] format to [MM/DD/YYYY] format

Tags: r

I want to retain the format of a Date column with "-" instead of "/". Currently `write.csv` automatically makes the above conversion and I haven't found any way to prevent this. To recreate the issue, I have used the free `hflights` dataset

```
library(hflights)
hflights2 <- hflights[1:5,1:5]
hflights2$New_Date = paste0(hflights2$Year,"-",hflights2$Month,"-",hflights2$DayofMonth)
write.csv(hflights2,"hflights2.csv")
```

Comment: Where do you check this result? In Excel? I would delete this quickly if I were you

Comment: Yes, but only because the end user wants to see that result in Excel, and he is particular about being able to see the date in that format.

Comment: Excel is doing the formatting- not R, don't you understand?

Comment: I get it David. I am clear on that. But my question now is, if there's anything at all that i can do in R, that when Excel receives the data, the formatting does not occur. And it sounds like the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

As David already remarked, you fell for a common error:

```
R> library(hflights)
R> hf2 <- hflights[1:5,1:5]
R> hf2$New_Date = paste0(hf2$Year,"-",hf2$Month,"-",hf2$DayofMonth)
R> write.csv(hf2,"/tmp/hflights2.csv")
R> system("cat /tmp/hflights2.csv")
"","Year","Month","DayofMonth","DayOfWeek","DepTime","New_Date"
"5424",2011,1,1,6,1400,"2011-1-1"
"5425",2011,1,2,7,1401,"2011-1-2"
"5426",2011,1,3,1,1352,"2011-1-3"
"5427",2011,1,4,2,1403,"2011-1-4"
"5428",2011,1,5,3,1405,"2011-1-5"
R>
```

There are a couple of issues here:

1. There is no error. R wrote exactly what you told it to.
2. There is a subtle error. You reformat dates as strings.  That is almost always a terrible idea.  Let the *type-aware* code handle this.

Ie use the Date-parsing code to construct a date from the components, then use that date type to format whatever form you like.  For dates, two digits for month and day are highly recommended.